# Play m3u as a list on iOS open network streams directly without downloading

Tags: ios, audio, streaming

## Issue

- [VLC iOS do not play m3u as a list](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-ios/-/issues/1345)

## What I tried

- use a javascript player via browser [codepen](https://codepen.io/craigstroman/pen/aOyRYx)
- Test [m3u file](https://biker-elegant.github.io/Stackoverflow-m3u/static_files/play.m3u)

  - VLC iOS do not work as a list

    [image: VLC iOS do not work as a list]
  - VLC Android works as a list correctly

    [image: VLC Android works as a list correctly]

Comment: Files required WebDAV or SMB access on the server side, does your server offer this?

Comment: Also, if this is more about finding a hosting service which does offer WebDAV/SMB, the question might not be a good fit for AD.

Comment: And, if this is purely about media files, VLC might be the better choice than Files.

Comment: Explaining why certain apps won’t help us useful. Even more useful would be to explain in more detail what you actually want to accomplish, without already assuming that certain technologies like git might be the solution.